# Clarification on statement if and only if

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, density-function

From my understanding, to prove a statement "something is an **A** if and only if it is a **B**" we start with **B** which will lead to **A**, then we start with **A** which will lead to **B**. In this case (please see the screenshot), **A** is: $$f_X(x) = \frac1{\sigma}f((x-\mu)/\sigma))$$ and **B** are $$f_Z(z)$$ and  $$X = \sigma Z + \mu$$ If so, why didn't the "only if" part of the attached proof start with **A**, that is, $f_X(x) = \frac1{\sigma}f((x-\mu)/\sigma))$? However, that would lead to $f_X(x) = \frac1{\sigma}f(z)$ instead of $f(z)$. Note: I derived the last equality ($f_X(x) = \frac1{\sigma}f(z)$) based on the premise that $z = g(x) = (x - \mu)/\sigma$. I'm so confused with the second part (only if) of the attached screenshot. Could you please point it out what I did wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the editing, @StubbornAtom. This will help me know how to post better in the future.